# Iterate over an array and add values to second array based on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have to pass the values from one array to the other, with the condition that the name start with "A".

```js
var favorites = []
var famous = [
  'alex smith', 'amy whinehouse', 
  'cameron diaz', 'brad pitt', 
  'ashton kutcher', 'mark whalberg', 
  'morgan freeman', 'mila kunis']
for (var i=0; i<famous.length; i++ ) { 
  if(famous[i][0]==="a") {
    favorites.push((famous[i][0]).unshift()) 
  }
}
```

The console return me an error.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with the `unshift()`? doesn't seem needed to just copy the values to another array. And also the root of your problem. `favorites.push(famous[i])` should work if I understand correctly what you're trying to do.

Comment: `famous[i][0]` is not an array, so `famous[i][0].unshift()` fails. What are you trying to do here? What is the goal of this code?

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 you could write it like this:

```js
var famous = ['alex smith', 'amy whinehouse', 'cameron diaz', 'brad pitt', 'ashton kutcher', 'mark whalberg', 'morgan freeman', 'mila kunis']
var favorites = famous.filter(artist => artist[0] == 'a');
 
console.log(favorites)
```

Your original code should have looked like this:

```js
var favorites = []
var famous = ['alex smith', 'amy whinehouse', 'cameron diaz', 'brad pitt', 'ashton kutcher', 'mark whalberg', 'morgan freeman', 'mila kunis']
for (var i=0; i<famous.length; i++) { 
    if (famous[i][0]==='a') {
        favorites.push(famous[i]); 
    }
}
console.log(favorites)
```

Your error code `TypeError: famous[i][0].unshift is not a function` indicates that you were trying to use an array function on something that is not an array. You were calling the function `unshift` on a string but for strings that function simply doesn't exist.

Comment: You don't need ES6 to use `.filter` you would simply need to do `famous.filter(function(artist) { return artist[0] == 'a' })`

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter method

```js
var favorites = [];
var famous = [
  'alex smith', 'amy whinehouse', 
  'cameron diaz', 'brad pitt', 
  'ashton kutcher', 'mark whalberg', 
  'morgan freeman', 'mila kunis'];
  
var favorites = famous.filter((artist, index) => {
  if (artist[0] == 'a') {
    delete famous[index];
    return true
  }
  return false;
});  
famous = famous.filter(Boolean)

console.log(famous)
console.log(favorites)
```